# Outlook Add-In's stoped working, because outlook web interface want to confirm domain using dialog which is blocked by browser

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, allow-modals

Somewhere between 13.Oct and today (16. Oct) I (and no one else in our company) can no longer use Outlook Add-Ins in Outlook. This is true for Add-Ins added by the user and Add-Ins deployed by the administrator. (We do not have Add-Ins installed from the Store)

The website started asking if the domain is trusted with a confirmation dialog. However this seems to be prevented by the browser (chrome and Firefox) I assume because the `allow-modals` is not set on the frame that hosts the Add-In. I tested to manipulate the website using fiddler to include the `allow-modals` and the dialog appeared and after confirmation the add-in worked.

[image: Confirmation Dialog]

Our Admin says he did not update the Exchange server in the past days. Since It happens in multiple browsers now, I also suspect it was not an silent update of the browser.

We are using the "old" OWA UI. And the Add-Ins open a task panel to the side. This displays an error:

[image: Error in Panel]

The English version has following Text:

> This add-in has been disabled to help keep you safe. To continue using the add
> in, validate that this item is hosted in a trusted domain or open it in the
> Office desktop app.

Using the continue button does nothing. (It shows a text that nothing can be done, without providing any information)

Does anyone have an Idea what could have changed? And how to turn it back or mitigate it?
Some Add-In are deployed by the Admin, so the User should not need to confirm the domain is trusted.

Comment: I found an [gihub issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1441) about this.

Comment: Please update the Exchange Server to the latest SU that was released on October 13, 2020. It has the code changes required for add-ins to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `office-js` script that was included by CDN was updated, breaking the Add-In. It needs an update released two days earlier for Exchange.

So I see two solutions.

1. Always update your Exchange the day the update is released
2. Use a fixed version from the NPM repository and update the version manually

Comment: How do i know what version of office-js should i be using with my exchange?

Comment: I fear try and error. You could also look in the change log. For me it was not so hard, since I knew it worked a few weeks earlier. So I just tried it with one or two different versions from NPM until it worked again.