# Installing Add-in In Exchange Server 2016 CU 12

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-web-addins

I have one extension which is working perfectly fine in office365 outlook but when I am trying to install the outlook client exchange server I am getting the following issue.

> This add-in has been disabled to keep you safe. To continue using the add-in validate that this item is hosted in a trusted domain or open it in the Office desktop app.

There is a 'continue' button however clicking simply shows 'sorry we can't continue

[image: Here's the issue when I click the icon]

I tried using different edge, chrome, and ie explorer but did not work out. Also, try by disabling all security features of the exchange server. I am using windows server 2016 with ES 2016 and CU 12 on windows server 2016.

> Name                : EC2AMAZ-0OQ14RF
> Edition             : StandardEvaluation
> AdminDisplayVersion : Version 15.1 (Build 1713.5)

Comment: Could you clarify where you see this error? You mentioned installing, do you see this error as part of installing the addin?  If you see this error from Outlook client, could you clarify if you are seeing this from Outlook client, could you clarify if you are using OWA or Outlook on Windows or Outlook on Mac?  A screenshot showing the error and step you took that led to the error will help us understand the issue better.

Comment: What is the requirement set specified in the manifest file? Is it supported by the Exchange server version?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I added , the example add-in which i am trying to install on inside my OWA.

Comment: Please update the server to the latest SU and this should get fixed. If you are facing any errors while updating, kindly check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/client-connectivity/exchange-security-update-issues#upgrade-patch-cant-be-installed

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, maybe this is related (from Hoxhunt Knowledge base):

**Error message**

*This add-in has been disabled to help keep you safe. To continue using the add-in, validate that this item is hosted in a trusted domain or open it in the Office desktop app.*

**Explanation**

This error is caused by a security patch done by Microsoft to their officejs (Office JavaScript) repository Oct 2020.

**Solution**

Recent Security Update to Exchange Servers is required to fix the error in OWA.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4581424/description-of-the-security-update-for-exchange-server-october-2020

https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2020-16969

**More technical information**

[Outlook Add-In's stoped working, because outlook web interface want to confirm domain using dialog which is blocked by browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64386431/outlook-add-ins-stoped-working-because-outlook-web-interface-want-to-confirm-d)

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1441

Comment: When i tried to update it , i am getting following error
https://ibb.co/mXb4vKK I tried all 2016 patches